# HTML Heading not changing on React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was doing a React JS youtube course and in one of the projects where I am building a Travel Advisory website I am failing to change the heading of the Header text. This is the header.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Autocomplete } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { AppBar,Toolbar,Typography,InputBase,Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';


import useStyles from './styles'

const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return(
        <AppBar position='static'>
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                
                <Typography variant='h4' className={classes.title}/>
                    Travel Advisor
                <Typography/>
                <Box display='flex'>
                    <Typography variant='h6'  className={classes.title}/>
                        Explore new places
                    <Typography/>
                    {/*<Autocomplete>*/}
                        <div className={classes.search}>
                            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                                <searchIcon/>
                            </div>
                            <InputBase placeholder='Search...' classes={{root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput}} />
                        </div>
                    {/*</Autocomplete>*/}
                </Box>  

            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

The link to the youtube video is : [Build and Deploy 5 JavaScript & React API Projects in 10 Hours - Full Course | RapidAPI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDa8kZLNhJ4&list=WL&index=3&t=1206s)

I have attached some screenshots for better reference

[This is what is getting shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUET9.png)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPjC.png)

[This is how the website is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMgI5.png)

I haven’t been able to make any progress with this issue so far

Comment: Did you happen to try other typography variants ? Like H1 or so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this package [react-helemt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) to change the React Page Headings.